# Access to items of a generated list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'd like to access to the first item of a generated list of components.

For example, in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/sinsedrix/pen/NWWrPgj), I want to trigger a click on the first item of a preset list, thus other components will update following the new value.

I guess I need a mix between `useEffect` and/or `useRef`, but I'm not at ease with these concepts yet.

[image]

Comment: Why not just set the `default` to be the 1st of the presets ? See https://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/yLLJYeY?editors=0010

Comment: In this case, selecting a preset has an effect on a sibling component (filling fields). So I don't want to set the first radio to checked and the other component to values corresponding to the first preset. That's why I need to trigger a click that would be handled to update the other's component state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to trigger a click on the first preset by using a ref callback.
It means the radio inputs have a `ref={refCallback}` attibute that points to the following callback.
I'm not sure it's the best way to do what I want and other answers are welcome.

```
const refCallback = React.useCallback(node => {
  if (node && node.value === presets[0].id) {
    node.click();
  }
}, [presets]);
```

Here is the updated [CodePen](https://codepen.io/sinsedrix/pen/gOOwXYe).